# Función Jquery que invoca un devuelve undefined ajax se conecta controller ASP Core 3

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp

Hola quisiera que me ayudaran con algo que estoy haciendo he leído pero algo no he entendido porque no lo hago funcionar los pongo en contexto:

Necesito llamar un % de una tabla y como es en ejecución quiero hacer un get en el controller tengo esto:

```
      public async Task<JsonResult> GetTaxPercen(int id)
      {
           try
           { 
                impuesto Item = await _iImp.ObtenerPorId(id);

                return Json(Item);
           }
           catch(Exception e)
           {
                return Json(e.Message);
           }
      }
```

Dicho sea de paso que "Item" lleva 5 registros tiene datos.
Intento llamar esta función con un Ajax  en Jquery:

```
function getImpuesto(id) {
var iUrl = "/Mov/GetTaxPercen?id=" + id;

$.ajax({
    url: iUrl,
    type: 'GET',
    data: '{}',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    asyn: true,
    success: function (result) {
        if (result != null) {
            return result.porcentaje;
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        return result.responseText;
    }
});
```

};

Esta es invocada de otra función jquery:

```
$("#neto").on("change keyup paste", function () {
if ($.isNumeric($("#neto").val())) {

    var pimp = self.getImpuesto(3);

    if (pimp > 0) {
        pimp = pimp / 100;

        if ($("#neto").val() > 0) {
            $("#iva").val(parseFloat($("#neto").val() * pimp).toFixed(2));
            $("#monto").val(parseFloat(parseFloat($("#neto").val()) + parseFloat($("#iva").val())).toFixed(2));
        }
    }

}
else { DesplegarModal('Advertencia Error', 'Necesita ingresar un valor númerico valido'); }
```

});

El problema es que el ajax si me retorna el valor pero no se manejar el asyncrono en jqueryu y me devuelve undefined como puedo hacer para que espere  asigne los valores?

Gracias si tienen algún ejemplo para leer lo agradeceré

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primero tienes que entender que un metodo asincrono se ejecuta en segundo plano osea que no es secuencial y no espera a que termine, estas peticiones nacierón para evitar que las paginas se pegaran esperando un proceso tardado y para evitar tener que recargar la pagina, te invito a leer más acerca de metodos asincronos. Tomando en cuenta lo anterior tu problema esta cuando usas **return en el metodo ajax**, ya que el metodo te devuelve inmediatamente aunque la petición no hubiera terminado.

Lo que tienens que hacer es mover tu codigo puedes crear un metodo que se ejecute cuando termine la petición, entonces el flujo quedaria asi: invocas tu petición ajax (se hace en 2do plano) supongamos que tarda 30 segundos, a los 30 segundos que responda llegara al metodo **success** aqui tu invocas tu nuevo metodo para que muestre el porcetaje.

Seria algo asi:

**Aqui invocarias el metodo asincronico:**

> $("#neto").on("change keyup paste", function () { if
>   ($.isNumeric($("#neto").val())) {
>
> ```
> getImpuesto(3);
>
>  } else { DesplegarModal('Advertencia Error', 'Necesita ingresar un valor númerico valido'); } }
> ```

**Metodo ajax.**

```
function getImpuesto(id) {
var iUrl = "/Mov/GetTaxPercen?id=" + id;

$.ajax({
    url: iUrl,
    type: 'GET',
    data: '{}',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    asyn: true,
    success: function (result) {
        if (result != null) {
           //el método que mostrara el valor en pantalla (se ejecuta cuando termine la solicitud, ej 30 segundos)
           mostrarPorcentaje(result.porcentaje;);
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log(result.responseText);
    }
});
```

**Metodo para mostrar en pantalla el valor**

```
mostrarPorcentaje(pimp) {
if (pimp > 0) {
        pimp = pimp / 100;

        if ($("#neto").val() > 0) {
            $("#iva").val(parseFloat($("#neto").val() * pimp).toFixed(2));
            $("#monto").val(parseFloat(parseFloat($("#neto").val()) + parseFloat($("#iva").val())).toFixed(2));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: muchas gracias voy pillando como se hace, intentare de esa forma y comentare los resultados.Saludos

Comment: Funciono genial muchas gracias